# docker Container command '/hello' not found or does not exist after switching hard drive

Tags: docker

I have changed my hard drive and before switching I copied all data from old hard drive to new one using `rsync`. Everything is working fine in the new SSD. However, I wasn't able to run docker containers. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and tried the example command in the docs:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

But I am getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '/hello' not found or does not exist..
```

Not sure if it is related to storage drivers since it was working fine on my old HDD. I tried changing the storage drivers in the `/etc/default/docker` file by modifying the line:

```
# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --storage-driver=devicemapper"
```

It switches to `devicemapper` but I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

try to change "build: ." to "image hello-world" in .yml file

Comment: where does it get stored ? I am using Ubuntu 14.04